# Using legacy themes with Android L

Tags: android, android-theme

I'm building an app and it supports any android version from 4.0+. I don't want an action bar so I'm using the theme `Holo.NoActionBar`. My question is if I use that will it still display the same on Android L, e.g. without the ActionBar, and if not what is the correct settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will still display the same on Android L. None of the Holo themes were changed in a way that would affect how existing apps are styled.